# Non-constant array size-initialization?

Tags: c++, arrays

From C++ document http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/
To define an array like this `int a[b];` the variable b must be a constant.

Here is what I am running under g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

```
int main(){
    int a = 10;
    int b[a];

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << b[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

variable `a` is not a constant and I have no error. May I ask start from what version of g++ will accept this kind of array definition?

Comment: Well, in this case I expect the compiler optimizes `a` out so that you are, in fact, initializing with a constant.  Try instead initializing with `rand()/100000` and see what happens (`#include <cstdlib>`)

Comment: @MattPhillips doubt that, the optimizer comes in long after that.

Comment: @MattPhillips: Optimization shouldn't be relevant. The language rules require a *constant expression*, and that doesn't *just* mean something that the compiler is able to figure out how to evaluate at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is using a non-standard extension. Your code isn't valid, standard C++. Variable length arrays aren't a feature of C++.

Note that the size has to be a compile-time constant, not merely a constant (i.e. `const`).

Comment: "Variable length arrays aren't a feature of C++" yet

Comment: @PeterT hopefully, never.

Comment: I meant [this](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3639.html) could be in C++14. I don't particularly like it either, but some people seem to want it badly. Not to mention all the new special restrictions that they have will only confuse beginners

Answer (score 4):

Variable length arrays are allowed as an extension in GCC.

See [GCC Docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Variable-Length.html#Variable-Length).

Answer (score 1):

You can't create dynamic arrays in C++, because your compiler needs to know how big your program is before compiling.
But to you can create an array with 'new':

`int *b = new int[a];`

This will create a new array reserving new storage.
You can access this array the normal way.

```
for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
{
   b[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a dynamically sized array you can use a std::vector in C++ (not exactly an array, but close enough and the backing store is available to you if you need the raw array). If you insist on creating a dynamic block of data you can simply use 'new type[]'.

```
int a = 100;
int[] b = new int[a];
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but this is not I want.